# Create student accounts using django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, web-development-server, django-admin-tools

I want to be able to create student user accounts using django admin interface which can be used by students to log in on my website?

Any sort of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking for code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    stu_name = models.CharField(_(""), max_length=50)
    stu_rolnumber = models.models.AutoField(primaryKey=true)
    stu_name = models.CharField(_(""), max_length=50)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    etc 
    stu_image =models.ImageField(_(""),  
   def __str__(self):
        return self.stu_rolnumber
```

Comment: Now I just need to register it in admin.py right?

Comment: yes ! Just write in admin.py  " from .models import Student   admin.site.register(Student)"